# Create a Cantor set on $[0,1]$ by removing $2^k$ open intervals each of length $a/3^k$ where $a \in (0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Create a Cantor like set on $[0,1]$ by removing $2^k$ open intervals each of length $a/3^k$ where $a \in (0,1]$ and compute its outer measure.

The proposed construction of the Cantor set here looks wrong to me. Can someone explain if this actually makes sense and what I'm missing? Suppose $a=1$. On the first step, we would remove two intervals of length $1/3$ -- a length of $2/3$ removed. On the second step, we would remove $2^2=4$ intervals of length $1/3^2 = 1/9$ -- a length of $4/9$. By now, we have $2/3 + 4/9 > 1$ removed from the interval of length $1$ so the construction seems invalid. Is this right?

Comment: Exponent mistake, one removes $2^k$ intervals of length $\frac{a}{3^{k+1}}$, so in the $0$-th step one interval of length $\frac{a}{3}$, then two intervals of length $\frac{a}{9}$ each, then ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Fischer pointed out the issue in a comment. If you prefer to number steps starting from $k=1$, then at the $k$th step you remove $2^{k-1}$ intervals of length $a/3^k$ each. It goes like this:

Suppose $a=1$. On the first step, we would remove **one** interval  of length $1/3$ -- a length of $1/3$ removed. On the second step, we would remove $2^1=2$ intervals of length $1/3^2 = 1/9$ -- a length of $2/9$. And so forth... for the total removed length
$$
\frac13+\frac29+\dots = \frac13\frac{1}{1-2/3} = 1
$$
With the factor of $a$ you get $a$ instead of $1$ in the sum.